# Can I add a key named 'keys' to a hashtable without overriding the 'keys' member

Tags: powershell, hashtable

It seems that I cannot add an arbitrary key name to a `hashtable` without overriding a member with that name if it already exists.

I create a hash table (`$x`) and add two keys, `one` and `two`:

```
$x = @{}

$x['one'] = 1
$x['two'] = 2
```

The added keys are then shown by evaluating `$x.Keys`:

```
$x.Keys
```

This prints:

```
one
two
```

If I add another key, named `keys`, it overrides the already existing member:

```
$x['Keys'] = 42

$x.Keys
```

This now prints:

```
42
```

I am not sure if I find this behavior desirable. I had expected `$x.keys` to print the key names and `$x['keys']` to print `42`.

Is it somehow possible to add a key named `Keys` without overriding the `Keys` member?

Comment: The member property is still there —> `$x.psobject.members['keys'].value`.

Comment: They online documentation specifically calls out the scenario of key name and member property collisions. The official stance is to use `$x.psbase.keys`

Comment: @AdminOfThings why don't you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the member property `Keys` still exists. It is just no longer accessible using the member access operator syntax `object.property`. You can see the property by drilling down into the `PSObject` sub-properties.

```
$x.PSObject.Members['Keys'].Value
```

The documentation for [Hash Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7) considers the scenario for property collisions. The recommendation for those cases is to use `hashtable.psbase.Property`.

```
$x.PSBase.Keys
```

For cases where collisions are unpredictable, you can use the hidden member method `get_Keys()` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60810458/is-it-correct-to-use-the-get-keys-method-for-collections).

```
$hash.get_Keys()
```

Comment: If you don't know the keys upfront (e.g. for a solution like [Powershell Merge 2 lists Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46091947/1701026)),  `PSBase` just moves the problem, consider: `$hash = @{Keys = 'MyKeys'; PSBase = 'MyPSBase'}`. Therefore I am often using the `get_Keys()` ***method*** for this. But as I can't find back were that was purposed and hardly any documentation on this method, I guess there is a pitfall behind this...

Comment: I just posted a official question for this: [Is it correct to use the get_Keys() method for collections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60810458/1701026)

Comment: @iRon, Thanks. I linked to your question. I think the online documentation should mention this.