# Is it correct to use the get_Keys() method for collections

Tags: .net, powershell, methods, collections, hashtable

Related to this question: [Can I add a key named 'keys' to a hashtable without overriding the 'keys' member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60803441/1701026)
, I am actually often using the `get_Keys()` *method* as the recommended `PSBase` *property* will just move the problem.
In other words, this method appears especially handy for an unknown list of directory keys in case of a solution like: [Powershell Merge 2 lists Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46091947/1701026).

The method works as expected (also on other collections, any PowerShell version and .Net Core):

```
$Hash = @{Keys = 'MyKeys'; PSBase = 'MyPSBase'}
$Hash.get_Keys()
PSBase
Keys
```

The `get_Keys()` method is apparently derived from:

```
$Hash.get_Keys

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Collections.ICollection get_Keys()
System.Collections.ICollection IDictionary.get_Keys()
```

The point is that I can't find back where I found the referral to this `get_Keys()` method and there is hardly any documentation about this method.
Is it safe to use this method?

Comment: Perhaps you can checkout the source code? I'm curious as well because I have never seen `get_Keys()`.

Comment: @RoadRunner , sorry but I don't have enough `C` knowledge myself to checkout the source code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_Keys()` is indeed a valid (and recommended) way to access [the `Keys` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary.keys?) of a dictionary without risking collision with a user-defined key.

> The method works as expected (also on other collections, any PowerShell version and .Net Core):

Please beware that this only works on **dictionaries** (`[hashtable]`, `[ordered]`, `[SortedList]` etc.) - as it's inherited from [the `System.Collections.IDictionary` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary).

The reason `get_Keys()` isn't listed in the public documentation is that it's *intentionally hidden*.

To understand why, we first need to understand the nature of **properties** in .NET

## Properties in .NET

In .NET, data types can have different kinds of *members*. In the (C#) example below we define a class with two members, a *field* and a *method*:

```
class MyClass
{
    int MyField;

    int MyMethod(string n = "")
    {
        return int.Parse(n);
    }
}
```

The interesting thing to notice here is that the field *acts like a variable* - we can reference it to obtain the value of whatever integer is stored in `MyField` and we can assign a (new) value to it. The method, on the other hand, *acts like a function* - we can call it, including passing parameter values to it, and it can return a value.

But .NET has a third kind of member type that acts as a bit of a *hybrid* between a field and a method, and it looks a bit like this (in the case of a dictionary):

```
class MyDictionary
{
    string[] _keys;
    
    public string[] Keys
    {
        get
        {
            return _keys;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't mess with the keys!");
        }
    }
}
```

This is known as a *property* - from a user perspective, the `Keys` property will act just like a field - we can reference it to resolve its value and we can (attempt to) assign to it - but from an implementer's perspective we have a lot more control over it's behavior, like being able to (conditionally) throw an exception on assignment.

Now, when the above code is compiled, the C# compiler needs to store the `get` and `set` methods *somewhere* so that the CLR knows to execute them when someone tries to resolve the `Keys` member at runtime.

The convention is to generate them as regular class methods, named by prepending `get_` and `set_` to the property name in question. The compiler further marks these methods with the [`SpecialName` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.specialnameattribute) flag, allowing editors and analyzers to hide them in user interfaces and auto-completers - which is exactly why the method name doesn't automatically show up in intellisense and the likes.

## Discovering property getters/setters

*In PowerShell classes, members are always either *methods* or *properties*, so in the following I'll use this PowerShell class definition for the examples:

```
class StackOverflowUser
{
  [string]$Name
  [int]$ID

  StackOverflowUser([string]$name, [int]$id)
  {
    $this.Name = $name
    $this.ID   = $ID
  }
}

$Mathias = [StackOverflowUser]::new("Mathias R. Jessen", 712649)
```

### Using `Get-Member`

You can discover the automatic getters and setters associated with a property using `Get-Member -Force`:

```
PS C:\> $Mathias |Get-Member ?et_* -Force


   TypeName: StackOverflowUser

Name     MemberType Definition
----     ---------- ----------
get_ID   Method     int get_ID()
get_Name Method     string get_Name()
set_ID   Method     void set_ID(int )
set_Name Method     void set_Name(string )
```

Here we can see the getter and setter methods associated with `$ID` and `$Name`.

### Using reflection

We can also find these directly from a `[type]` object:

```
PS C:\> $IDPropertyInfo = [StackOverflowUser].GetProperty("ID")
PS C:\> $IDPropertyInfo.GetMethod

Name                       : get_ID
DeclaringType              : StackOverflowUser
ReflectedType              : StackOverflowUser
MemberType                 : Method
MetadataToken              : 100663299
Module                     : RefEmit_InMemoryManifestModule
IsSecurityCritical         : True
IsSecuritySafeCritical     : False
IsSecurityTransparent      : False
MethodHandle               : System.RuntimeMethodHandle
Attributes                 : PrivateScope, Public, HideBySig, SpecialName
CallingConvention          : Standard, HasThis
ReturnType                 : System.Int32
ReturnTypeCustomAttributes : Int32
ReturnParameter            : Int32
IsCollectible              : True
IsGenericMethod            : False
IsGenericMethodDefinition  : False
ContainsGenericParameters  : False
MethodImplementationFlags  : Managed
IsAbstract                 : False
IsConstructor              : False
IsFinal                    : False
IsHideBySig                : True
IsSpecialName              : True
IsStatic                   : False
IsVirtual                  : False
IsAssembly                 : False
IsFamily                   : False
IsFamilyAndAssembly        : False
IsFamilyOrAssembly         : False
IsPrivate                  : False
IsPublic                   : True
IsConstructedGenericMethod : False
CustomAttributes           : {}
```

Notice that the getter above has the `SpecialName` attribute as discussed above

*Note: output above is from PowerShell 7 and will be **slightly** different in Windows PowerShell due to changes in the reflection/type system APIs in .NET Core*

I hope this explains :)